# How can I run a database query in code?

Tags: 8, database

I want something like `SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = "blablabla"`.

How do I do this in Drupal 8 PHP code?

Comment: There is a full topic on Drupal.org API. It is not possible to answer the question without repeating what already said in the documentation. If you had problems with code you are writing, you could ask a question about that, providing you show the code you are using.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the answer given here is not even complete, since it doesn't cover all the available methods.

Comment: To use pure SQL save the querry string in the $sql variable and do this: 
`$connection = \Drupal::database();
        $query = $connection->query($sql);
        $result = $query->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would use the [database abstraction layer](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x).

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'nid');
$query->condition('n.type', 'blablabla');
$results = $query->execute();
```

As for executing the query, you can also [fetch results in various ways](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21StatementInterface.php/interface/StatementInterface/8.2.x).

Examples:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'nid');
$query->condition('n.type', 'blablabla');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();


$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'nid');
$query->condition('n.type', 'blablabla');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```

If you are within a class, you should inject the appropriate classes in your constructor instead of use the static Drupal container. But since you are in a preprocess function, `\Drupal::database()` is fine.

From `core/lib/Drupal.php`:

```
 /**
   * Returns the current primary database.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
   *   The current active database's master connection.
   */
  public static function database() {
    return static::getContainer()->get('database');
  }
```

Depending on your use case(s), you can also leverage [EntityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x):

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'blablabla');
$results = $query->execute();
```

Please note that you may want to use `node_field_data` table instead of `node`, but your query is pretty generic so it is hard to tell without a better query.

Example, get all nodes of type that are published:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'nfd');
$query->addField('nfd', 'nid');
$query->condition('nfd.type', 'blablabla');
$query->condition('nfd.status', 1);
$results = $query->execute();
```

Or:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'blablabla');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the kind of simple answer I was looking for :)

Comment: Updated with a couple of examples. Little hard to give better direction, but this should get you into the DB APIs. Also, if you add more details to your question, like what your objective may be in a preprocess function (show node counts?) it can be reopened.

Comment: $pager_data = $this->database->select('table_a', 'a');
    $pager_data->fields('a', array('field1', 'field2'));
    $pager_data->join('ges_casse','b','b.id=a.bid');
    $pager_data->fields('b', array('field3'));
    $pager_data->orderBy('nid', 'DESC');
    $pager_data->extend(PagerSelectExtender::class)->limit(4);
    $pager_final_data = $pager_data->execute()->fetchAll();
    dpm($pager_final_data);